# Is there any way to extend a Array without copy or without using Arraylist and increase the array size dynamically?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Say for example if I have a array A. I should not increase the array size by using Array copy or I should not use Arraylist.

Comment: Not possible unless you use list embedded with an array internally i.e. creating your own data structure which would be worse!

Comment: Sounds like homework. Why would you not want to use ArrayCopy or Arraylist otherwise?

Comment: Is that the actual problem you are trying to solve or a problem with your solution to a different problem?

Comment: @WJS I was trying to reduce the time of array manipulation. I tried copy new array and arraylist. Like to search the different way where I can still reduce the time consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should not increase the array size by using Array copy or I should not use Arraylist

If you can't use `Arrays.copy()` and you can't use `ArrayList`, then just do the resize yourself, e.g.:

```
public static String[] increaseSize(String[] array, int newLength) {
    if (array.length >= newLength)
        return array;
    String[] newArray = new String[newLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    return newArray;
}
```

Since Java arrays are **fixed-size**, the only way to change the size is to create a new array and copy the elements. Whether doing it yourself, or using some API methods to help you, that's what has to happen.

There is no such thing as a *dynamically-sized array* in Java.